# Slack API - Generates: invalid_arg_name for SOME posts

Tags: slack-api

I have code that generates the following strings which are messaged to slack.
I have XXXd my token and Channel name.  Other than that - these are exact as they are sent to slack.

The code executes about 50 of these - and only SOME of them fail

Item 5 returns the error:invalid_arg_name

1. https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&pretty=0&username=CNS&channel=mychannel&text=List
   Updated:  7/26/2020 12:28 PM
2. https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&pretty=0&username=CNS&channel=mychannel&text=
   (Pops and Beverages ):   |1000|  Diet Cola - 2 Liter:  Order: 7 to 8 - 2-Liter"
3. https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&pretty=0&username=CNS&channel=mychannel&text=
   (Pops and Beverages ):   |0999|  Diet Cola - Pepsi - Cans:  Order: 3
   to 4 case
4. https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&pretty=0&username=CNS&channel=mychannel&text=
   (Seasoning ):   |0997|  Spices - Italian:  Order: 1 to 1 each
5. https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&pretty=0&username=CNS&channel=mychannel&text=
   (Breads & Cereal ):   |0974|  Bread - White Meijer Split Top:
   Order: 1 to 1 each

Comment: Does the API provide additional details about the error other than `error:invalid_arg_name`?

Comment: The whole URL Response is:
"{""ok"":false,""error"":""invalid_arg_name""}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your text before sending it to the API. In example 5, you are sending an unencoded ampersand ("Breads & Cereal"), causing the API to interpret everything after the ampersand as a query parameter name (thus the error, "invalid_arg_name").

Try sending it like that:

`https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&pretty=0&username=CNS&channel=mychannel&text=%20%28Breads%20%26%20Cereal%20%29%3A%20%7C0974%7C%20Bread%20-%20White%20Meijer%20Split%20Top%3A%20Order%3A%201%20to%201%20each`.

I recommend you to search for how to do *percent encoding* or *url encoding* in the programming language you are using.

Comment: Thank You - That was indeed the issue!!